# CKEditor: Plug-in button won't appear

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Using the latest CKEditor, I'm attempting to add their example plugin, "timestamp" from the documentation.  I downloaded all of the code from Github at the link they provided and put everything in the proper location.

The docs:  http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample
The github link: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs-samples/tree/master/tutorial-timestamp

```
ckeditor/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js
ckeditor/plugins/timestamp/icons/timestamp.png
ckeditor/plugins/timestamp/samples/timestamp.html
```

In the config.js file, I put in this line:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';
```

I've closed the browser, used other browsers that I haven't used in months, etc, and no matter what, the button icon never appears.

I've googled about this, and read several Q's here on StackOverflow.  Many have talked about misnamed icons or missing icons or whatever, but this time, it's all there, and it's all exactly as it came from Github.

Once this works, I can attempt to move over some plugins we have from an older CKEditor v4.0 installation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the plugin to ckeditor.replace as well. This is a simple example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                    extraPlugins: 'timestamp'
                }  );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The config.js file.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing'] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph', 'timestamp'] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];
    config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks... but sadly your suggested changes had no effect either.  The toolbar didn't change at all from the config you posted, so I'm really wondering if the config.js file is even being read.  I have Chrome Dev Tools open and no errors are appearing in the console.

Comment: Maybe try downloading ckeditor again. Mine is working fine with that config http://i.imgur.com/RF0bcfG.png. You are definitely running it on a server?

Comment: Downloaded it fresh, moved over the changes... same result.  The config.js is definitely being ignored.  I know because I had specified width/height in the CKEDITOR.replace code, and when I moved it to the config file, it had no effect and the size reverted to "stock."  I appreciate your help; looks like I have bigger problems.